# Logout doesn't seem to invalidate session

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm testing out the API as documented on https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Store+APIs

I can call the login, list apps and logout functions. However after calling logout I can still list my apps:

Login:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=83BD02EF499EF55E566EC26B58DDA756; Path=/store/; HttpOnly
...
```

List Apps:

```
$ curl -i -b cookies   http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag?action=getApplications
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
...    
{"error" : false, "applications" : [{"name" : "DefaultApplication", "tier" : "Unlimited", "id" : 1, "callbackUrl" : null, "status" : "APPROVED", "description" : null}]}
```

Logout:

```
$ curl -i -b cookies 'http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag?action=logout'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=224B416DEE99F9769BB0BACD85E337E6; Path=/publisher/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
...
{"error" : false}
```

List Apps:

```
$ curl -i -b cookies   http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag?action=getApplications
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
...    
{"error" : false, "applications" : [{"name" : "DefaultApplication", "tier" : "Unlimited", "id" : 1, "callbackUrl" : null, "status" : "APPROVED", "description" : null}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of a looking, the documentation is in error for the `curl` example. The URL for logging out should be:

```
$ curl -i -b cookies 'http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag?action=logout'
```

The URL in the documentation shows `publisher` in the URL of the `curl` example !

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Store+APIs#StoreAPIs-Logout

Answer (score 0):

Correct the query as below

```
curl -i -b cookies 'http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag?action=logout'
```

Comment: thanks @Nadeesha. This is what I did, as per my answer. I was really logging it here for others to see how to get around the problem and hope WSO2 might fix the doc bug :)

Comment: Yes I will raise a JIRA on this